# Problema redireccionamiento login AUTH

Tags: laravel

Cuando se logea el admin se supone que deberia redireccionarse a una vista llamada admin , pero en vez de eso cuando el admin se logea se redirecciona al login del usuario.

Web.php

```
Auth::routes();
 Route::prefix('admin')->group(function(){
Route::get('/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
Route::post('/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@login')->name('admin.login.submit');
Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index')->name('admindashboard');
});
```

Este el el adminlogincontroller

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest:admin');
}

public function showLoginForm()
{
    return view('auth.admin-login');
}

public function login( Request $request )
{

    // Validate form data
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email'     => 'required|email',
        'password'  => 'required|min:6'
    ]);

    // Attempt to authenticate user

    // If successful, redirect to their intended location
    if ( Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->remember) ) {
        return redirect()->intended( route('admindashboard') );
    }

    // Authentication failed, redirect back to the login form
    return redirect()->back()->withInput( $request->only('email', 'remember') );

}
```

}

este es el admincontroller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
   public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:admin');
    }


    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Estás usando el método `intended()`, el cual va a redireccionar a la página anterior o a la cual se intentaba acceder antes. Si dicha url no está disponible, entonces va a ir a la que le pases como parámetro de entrada.

Esto se puede ver en el código de dicho método:

```
public function intended($default = '/', $status = 302, $headers = [], $secure = null)
{
    $path = $this->session->pull('url.intended', $default);

    return $this->to($path, $status, $headers, $secure);
}
```

En tu caso puedes usar simplemente el método `route()` para redirigir a la ruta que deseas:

```
return redirect()->route('admindashboard');
```

Comment: Mira que me sigue redireccionando hacia el login de usuario :(